# Will the graphics of my processor and GPU combine?

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon, intel-graphics, intel-core-i7

I just bought an Intel i7 4770k with integrated HD 4600 graphics.  I also purchased an AMD 7790 GPU.  Will/Can these components run together to add more graphics power to my system, or is this implausible and inefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not generally be able to do this, although you could probably run a monitor off each system and share the processing power that way.

Part of the problem is that GPU's arn't designed to work this way, part would be that you are using 2 different GPU architectures (You might be able to do something like this if both were using the same architecture, in some special cases - I'm thinking of [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html))

Comment: If you're motherboard supports [Virtu MVP](http://www.lucidlogix.com/product-virtu-mvp.shtml) then you mostly can. Mostly, it just saves power when you're not playing games.